# How to disable Auto connect in street view through URL(programatically)

Tags: google-street-view, google-streetview-publish

By opening the Street View App with your account we can disable "Auto-connect 360 photos" in the settings...
but how to achieve this programatically..
when the user log in..i have to disable "Auto-connect 360 Photos" in the settings

Comment: Can you add any details like: code used, error problem encountered? [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Show the community what you have tried.

Comment: hi @abielita...

Comment: there is no code...actually how to turn off auto connect 360 through a http request